# one line placing inside overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-float

I try to make a slider but have trouble, with placing all my `div` tags in one line. How do I do that?
And how to do auto-width for `#slider_content`?

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 20px; background: #FFA; overflow:hidden">
        <div id="slider_content">
            <div style="width:50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; float:left">1</div>
            <div style="width:50px; height: 50px; background: #faa; float:left">2</div>
            <div style="width:50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; float:left">3</div>
            <div style="width:50px; height: 50px; background: #faa; float:left">4</div>
            <div style="width:50px; height: 50px; background: #ccc; float:left">5</div>
            <div style="width:50px; height: 50px; background: #faa; float:left">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of your outermost DIV is far too narrow - increase it to be at least 300px.
Alternatively set the widths of your innermost DIVs to be a percentage which total <= 100%, then set slider_content to have width of 100%.
e.g.

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 20px; background: #FFA; overflow:hidden">
    <div id="slider_content" style="width: 100%">
        <div style="width:15%; height: 50px; background: #ccc; float:left">1</div>
        <div style="width:15%; height: 50px; background: #faa; float:left">2</div>
        <div style="width:15%; height: 50px; background: #ccc; float:left">3</div>
        <div style="width:15%; height: 50px; background: #faa; float:left">4</div>
        <div style="width:15%; height: 50px; background: #ccc; float:left">5</div>
        <div style="width:15%; height: 50px; background: #faa; float:left">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it is work, but count of div's inside #slider_content can be different

Comment: If the count of the sliders can be different, calculate the number of divs before hand, then set each width to be `(100/N)%` (where N is your number of divs).

Answer (score 1):

you dont really need auto width just set it higher than what you require!

```
.slider_content{
width:1000px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It is solution but total width of all div's can be more then 1000px =(

Comment: then make it 10000px, i think you are just trying to over complicate the problem, if you are creating the item dynamically then set width based on the quantity of items in the slider list.